# Magento 2.3.1 - Advanced pricing error after customer login in frontend

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, customer-group, tiered-pricing, advanced-pricing

We are working with `Magento 2.3.1`. The cache is enabled.

We are experiencing strange behavior with the respective `customer groups` and the `advanced pricing`: It seems the customer groups somehow "slip out" after putting products into the shopping cart.

1.) We have *standard* customers and *business* customers

2.) When logged in as business customer one sees the advances (tier prices) of a product. Like [here](https://pasteboard.co/IyeUe60.jpg) All looks good. Advanced prices are showing.

3.) **Now when I put a product in the cart first problem is, that the advanced prices are not taken into the cart but only the standard prices.** **Then** when I go back continue shopping, still logged in as a business customer, **it does not show the advanced prices anymore at all**, but only the normal prices for non logged in private customers. See [here](https://pasteboard.co/IyeWmuV.jpg).

4.) Does anyone out there have a hint, what could have happened here, regarding the customer groups and the price display and add to cart function of the correct price?

I´d be super thankful for any help.

Best regards

Comment: Have any success in figuring this out?

Comment: Yes. We finally could fix this problem. One of our extensions caused the error here.